# Unique mapping of 3 integer parameters to an index in a lookup table with offset

Tags: c, dynamic-programming, memoization

I'm working on university assignment, where the goal is to design a recursive algorithm to compute the maximum size of a tower built using a sequence(s) of pallets under the condition that the pallet below should always be strictly larger then the pallets above.

I attempt to implement memoization with a lookup table to improve the efficiency of otherwise slow algorithm.

Below is my input processing:

```
int 
main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    int lookup_memb = 0;

    // read number of element in two stacks
    scanf("%i %i\n", &lenA, &lenB);

    // it's guaranteed for the first stack to always have more then zero elements
    stackA = (int*) malloc(lenA*sizeof(int));
    for (int i = 0; i < lenA; i ++) {
        scanf(" %i", stackA+i);
        stack_max = max(stack_max, stackA[i]);
    }

    // so far we estimate lookuptable size has to be at least lenA*stack_max;
    lookup_memb = lenA*stack_max;

    // however, second stack might be empty
    if (lenB) {
        stackB = (int*) malloc(lenB*sizeof(int));
        for (int i = 0; i < lenB; i ++) {
            scanf(" %i", stackB+i);
            stack_max = max(stack_max, stackB[i]);
        }

        // we have to override lookup_memb since we know stack B is not empty
        lookup_memb = lenA * lenB * stack_max;
        
    }

    
    lookup = (int*) calloc(lookup_memb, sizeof(int));
    printf("%i\n", solve2(stackA, stackB, lenA, lenB, stack_max));

    free(lookup);
    free(stackA);
    free(stackB);

    return 0;
}
```

Then in my solving routine's i make use of

```
static
inline 
int
idx(int llenA, int llenB, int constraint) {
    // I use local-length A as x coordinate
    // local-length B as y coordinate
    // and constraint as z coordinate

    return  llenA // final pad to the specific column in row and plane
            + llenB * lenA // pad to the specific row in a plane
            + constraint * lenB * lenA; // pad to a sepcific plane
}
```

to determine the offset in the table.

There is a bug in the code, and it seems to be caused by out of bound array access. Now this if expected, since I start my algorithm looking up solution for full length of A, full length of B, and maximum possible constraint. Which makes it 1 row and 1 column out of bound.

I can fix it by allocating extra space, taking lenA to be lenA + 1, lenB to be lenB + 1, and constraint to be constraint + 1, but that seems unnecessary since if values for lenA and lenB are both zero or value of constraint is zero (moreover, constraint is guaranteed to be larger then zero), hard coding the return of zero is easier and arguably more efficient.

This means that table already contains one extra row, and one extra plane. I'm curios, how can I shift my index function so the mapping is still unique but it uses full table reducing the extra allocation I have to make.

I was asked to provide minimal reproducible example for this question. Here it is, I was hesitant to include it int the question, since **I did not want to prompt people to provide a solution** since that would be academic dishonesty.

```
#include<malloc.h>
#include<stdio.h>

int* stackA = NULL;
int* stackB = NULL;
int* lookup = NULL;
int lenA = 0, lenB = 0;
int stack_max = 0;

// returns maximum of two integers
static inline int max(int a, int b); 

// maps unique set of parameters to a unique index in lookup table
static inline int idx(int llenA, int llenB, int constraint); 

// find the maximum height of a tower which can be built using a sequence of pallets
// under condition that every next level of the tower must be strictly larger then the next one
int solve1(int* stack, int llen, int constraint, int isA);

// find the maximum height of a tower which can be built using ywo sequences of pallets
// under condition that every next level of the tower must be strictly larger then the next one
int solve2(int* stackA, int* stackB, int llenA, int llenB, int constraint);

static
inline
int 
max(int a, int b) {
    return a < b ? b : a;
}

static
inline 
int
idx(int llenA, int llenB, int constraint) {
    // I use local-length A as x coordinate
    // local-length B as y coordinate
    // and constraint as z coordinate

    return  llenA // final pad to the specific column in row and plane
            + llenB * lenA // pad to the specific row in a plane
            + constraint * lenB * lenA; // pad to a sepcific plane
}

int 
solve1(int* stack, int llen, int constraint, int isA) {
    int fo,  // first-out element of the stack
        ret, // return value 
        // lookup index of return value for parameters given
        // if we have stack A remaining, we pass local-len as length of A, and pass 0 as length of B
        // if we have stack B remaining, we do the opposite 
        iself = idx(isA*llen, (!isA)*llen, constraint); 

    if (!llen) // if we have empty stack, we know the height of a tower we can build using it is 0
        return 0;

    // we first attempt to lookup the value, hoping it was already calculated
    ret = lookup[iself]; 
    if (ret) // calloc zeroes out lookup table, hence if ret is not zero it was already populated
        return ret;
    
    // if we got here, we know we have to compute the value
    fo = stack[0]; 

    // we either have the opportunity to take the pallet or we do not
    // in first case, we need to find whether it's better to use or discard the pallet
    // in second case we have no choice, we we discard the pallet
    ret = (constraint <= fo) ? solve1(stack+1, llen-1, constraint, isA) :  max(1 + solve1(stack+1, llen-1, fo, isA), solve1(stack+1, llen-1, constraint, isA));
    lookup[iself] = ret;
    return ret;
}

int 
solve2(int* stackA, int* stackB, int llenA, int llenB, int constraint) {

    int foA, // first-out element of stack A
        foB, // first-out element of stack B
        ret, // return value
        iself = idx(llenA, llenB, constraint); // lookup index of return value for parameters given
    
    if (!(llenA || llenB)) 
        return 0; // if both stacks are empty we know maximum height of a tower is zero

    // we first attempt to lookup the value, hoping that this calculation was already made
    ret = lookup[iself]; 
    if (ret) { // calloc zeroes out lookup table, hence if ret is not zero it was already populated
        return ret;
    }

    // if we got here, we must solve for value
    if (!llenA) { // if we only have stackB we simplify
        ret = solve1(stackB, llenB, constraint, 0);
        lookup[iself] = ret;
        return ret;
    }

    if (!llenB) { // likewise, if we only got stack A we simplify
        ret = solve1(stackA, llenA, constraint, 1);
        lookup[iself] = ret;
        return ret;
    }

    // if we got here, we must solve full problem   
    foA = stackA[0];
    foB = stackB[0];

    // if we decide to make choice based on stack A, we either have the opportunity to take the pallet or we do not
    // in the first case, we need to find whether it's better to take or discard the pallet
    // in the second case we have no choice, hence we just discard it
    int chooseA = foA < constraint ? max(1 + solve2(stackA+1, stackB, llenA-1, llenB, foA), solve2(stackA+1, stackB, llenA-1, llenB, constraint)) : solve2(stackA+1, stackB, llenA-1, llenB, constraint);
    
    // if we decide to make choice based on stack B, we either have the opportunity to take the pallet or we do not
    // in the first case, we need to find whether it's better to take or discard the pallet
    // in the second case we have no choice, hence we just discard it
    int chooseB = foB < constraint ? max(1 + solve2(stackA, stackB+1, llenA, llenB-1, foB), solve2(stackA, stackB+1, llenA, llenB-1, constraint)) : solve2(stackA, stackB+1, llenA, llenB-1, constraint); 
    
    // the solution for the current parameters is the maximum solution of stack A "route" and stack B "route"  
    ret = max(chooseA, chooseB);
    lookup[iself] = ret;

    return ret;
}

int 
main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    int lookup_memb = 0;

    // read number of element in two stacks
    scanf("%i %i\n", &lenA, &lenB);

    // it's guaranteed for the first stack to always have more then zero elements
    stackA = (int*) malloc(lenA*sizeof(int));
    for (int i = 0; i < lenA; i ++) {
        scanf(" %i", stackA+i);
        stack_max = max(stack_max, stackA[i]);
    }

    // so far we estimate lookuptable size has to be at least lenA*stack_max;
    lookup_memb = lenA*stack_max;

    // however, second stack might be empty
    if (lenB) {
        stackB = (int*) malloc(lenB*sizeof(int));
        for (int i = 0; i < lenB; i ++) {
            scanf(" %i", stackB+i);
            stack_max = max(stack_max, stackB[i]);
        }

        // we have to override lookup_memb since we know stack B is not empty
        lookup_memb = lenA * lenB * stack_max;
    }
    
    lookup = (int*) calloc(lookup_memb, sizeof(int));
    printf("%i\n", solve2(stackA, stackB, lenA, lenB, stack_max));

    free(lookup);
    free(stackA);
    free(stackB);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Step 1:  Drop the `\n` from `scanf("%i %i\n", &lenA, &lenB);`.

Comment: What is the value of `stack_max` the first time `stack_max = max(stack_max, stackA[i]);` is executed?  Post a [mcve].  Try compiling what you post.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica, why would that be different?

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica, here is a compliable, minimal reproducible example.

Comment: Herbal Tea, the `"\n"` reads white-space until encounters a non-white-space.  Thus `scanf("%i %i\n", &lenA, &lenB);` does not return until 2 numbers (as text) and some following non-white-space  is entered.  Due to buffered, this is often 2 lines.

Comment: What, about, are the largest `lenA, lenB` expected?  Might `lenA * lenB * stack_max`  or other indexing math overflow?  Should use `size_t` for indexing math.

Comment: General thought: "design a recursive algorithm" and global variables often do not work well together.  I do not know if that issue is causing your trouble here, but it does not smell right.

Comment: Please post a set of inputs that demo the problem.